# Small error I don't know how to fix, " not a statment"

Tags: java, syntax-error

What I am trying to do is take in input from an end user and write it to a file called **dictionary.txt**. Then I am trying to check that the word entered by the end user is not already in the dictionary.txt file because i don't want duplicates. If the word is not in the dictionary then it will get stored in the dictionary.txt. The problem that I am having is a `compilation error` which tells me that `Project3.java:81: not a statement FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);`.

```
public static void addNewWord()throws IOException
{
    String newWord = "";
    newWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the word you want to add to your dictionary.");
    String aLineFromFile = "";
    String filename = "dictionary.txt";
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    File resultsFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(resultsFile);

    while(inFile.hasNext())
         aLineFromFile = inFile.nextLine();
         if (aLineFromFile.startsWith(newWord))
         {
            dictionary.add(aLineFromFile);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word already is dictionary");
            addNewWord();
                 }

 else
    FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
    out.println(newWord);
    out.close();
    aDictionary.close();

  return;
}
```

I have imported `java.io.*; javax.swing.*; java.awt.Dimension; java.util.*;`
If someone can tell me why I am getting this error and tell me how to fix it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You're missing the "{" after "else".

Comment: after that check the while loop braces

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, generated a.m. exception

Comment: And also the one after "while", and your closing "}" characters.

Comment: @mKorbel - I think he posted the right stuff.

Comment: Your code style is hard to read and makes mistakes easier.  I'd pay a lot more attention to formatting if I were you.  I'd also recommend using a good IDE, like IntelliJ, to help prevent these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: I think you folks are being hard on the guy, with all the downvotes.  Guys that get waste-deep into Objective-C without understanding what an object is don't get treated half as harshly.

Answer (score 3):

Dont forget to indent well, it helps to see the missing braces and the scopes.

This should work better:

```
public static void addNewWord() throws IOException {
    String newWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the word you want to add to your dictionary.");
    String filename = "dictionary.txt";
    File resultsFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(resultsFile);
    List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        String aLineFromFile = inFile.nextLine();
        if (aLineFromFile.startsWith(newWord)) {
            dictionary.add(aLineFromFile);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word already is dictionary");
            addNewWord();
        } else {
            FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
            out.println(newWord);
            out.close();
            aDictionary.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put else code inide this `{}` block

like this

```
else{
         FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
         out.println(newWord);
         out.close();
         aDictionary.close();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following modified code. You missed the braces after while loop and else block

```
public static void addNewWord() throws IOException {
    String newWord = "";
    newWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the word you want to add to your dictionary.");
    String aLineFromFile = "";
    String filename = "dictionary.txt";
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    File resultsFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(resultsFile);

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        aLineFromFile = inFile.nextLine();
        if (aLineFromFile.startsWith(newWord)) {
            dictionary.add(aLineFromFile);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word already is dictionary");
            addNewWord();
        } else {
            FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
            out.println(newWord);
            out.close();
            aDictionary.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, but this is just the beginning of your problems:

```
    public static void addNewWord() throws IOException {
        String newWord;
        newWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the word you want to add to your dictionary.");
        String aLineFromFile = "";
        String filename = "dictionary.txt";
        ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
        File resultsFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(resultsFile);
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            aLineFromFile = inFile.nextLine();
            if (aLineFromFile.startsWith(newWord)) {
                dictionary.add(aLineFromFile);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word already is dictionary");
                addNewWord();
            } else {
                FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
                out.println(newWord);
                out.close();
                aDictionary.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think it's badly conceived.  There's no good reason for mingling functionality like this with UI/Swing classes.  Separate the two or you'll never be able to use this method without a Swing UI.  It's called layering or separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Better formatting:

```
public static void addNewWord()throws IOException {

    String newWord = "";
    newWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the word you want to add to your dictionary.");
    String aLineFromFile = "";
    String filename = "dictionary.txt";
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    File resultsFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(resultsFile);

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        aLineFromFile = inFile.nextLine();
        if (aLineFromFile.startsWith(newWord)) {
            dictionary.add(aLineFromFile);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word already is dictionary");
            addNewWord();
        }

        else {
            FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
            out.println(newWord);
            out.close();
            aDictionary.close();
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Maintain a 4-character indentation for code blocks, even if you have to do it individually with the space and delete keys (vs having an editor that does it for you).  It saves you time in the long-run.